# Combine/Merge two instances of InputDecoration in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have two instances of InputDecoration in flutter as follows:

```dart
    final firstStyle = InputDecoration(labelText: "hello", contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10));
    final secondStyle = InputDecoration(fillColor: Colors.lightBlue);
```

What I want now is combined form of these two instances so that that single combined or merged decoration can be applied to the input field, that means all three properties, `labelText`, `contentPadding`, `fillColor` will be applied.

I found something called `.merge()` for `TextStyle` but not for other classses like `InputDecoration` and `BoxDecoration`. What should I do?

Comment: That would've been a good feature. Unfortunately there exists nothing of sorts in the source code. Not sure why they left out for this class. But one way to overcome this problem is to make a custom class that can take two or more `InputDecoration`s and merge them.

Comment: Depending in the use case, consider using copyWith instead

Answer (score 4):

Use this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MergeInputDecoration {
  final InputDecoration input1;
  final InputDecoration input2;

  MergeInputDecoration({
    required this.input1,
    required this.input2,
  });

  InputDecoration merge() {
    return input1.copyWith(
      alignLabelWithHint: input2.alignLabelWithHint,
      border: input2.border,
      constraints: input2.constraints,
      contentPadding: input2.contentPadding,
      counter: input2.counter,
      counterStyle: input2.counterStyle,
      counterText: input2.counterText,
      disabledBorder: input2.disabledBorder,
      enabled: input2.enabled,
      enabledBorder: input2.enabledBorder,
      errorBorder: input2.errorBorder,
      errorMaxLines: input2.errorMaxLines,
      errorStyle: input2.errorStyle,
      errorText: input2.errorText,
      fillColor: input2.fillColor,
      filled: input2.filled,
      floatingLabelBehavior: input2.floatingLabelBehavior,
      floatingLabelStyle: input2.floatingLabelStyle,
      focusColor: input2.focusColor,
      focusedBorder: input2.focusedBorder,
      focusedErrorBorder: input2.focusedErrorBorder,
      helperMaxLines: input2.helperMaxLines,
      helperStyle: input2.helperStyle,
      helperText: input2.helperText,
      hintMaxLines: input2.hintMaxLines,
      hintStyle: input2.hintStyle,
      hintText: input2.hintText,
      hintTextDirection: input2.hintTextDirection,
      hoverColor: input2.hoverColor,
      icon: input2.icon,
      iconColor: input2.iconColor,
      isCollapsed: input2.isCollapsed,
      isDense: input2.isDense,
      label: input2.label,
      labelStyle: input2.labelStyle,
      labelText: input2.labelText,
      prefix: input2.prefix,
      prefixIcon: input2.prefixIcon,
      prefixIconColor: input2.prefixIconColor,
      prefixIconConstraints: input2.prefixIconConstraints,
      prefixStyle: input2.prefixStyle,
      prefixText: input2.prefixText,
      semanticCounterText: input2.semanticCounterText,
      suffix: input2.suffix,
      suffixIcon: input2.suffixIcon,
      suffixIconColor: input2.suffixIconColor,
      suffixIconConstraints: input2.suffixIconConstraints,
      suffixStyle: input2.suffixStyle,
      suffixText: input2.suffixText,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: A simple, but useful response. Thank you so much.

Comment: decoration.copyWith()

Answer (score 0):

You can also make an extension:

```
extension InputDecorationExtension on InputDecoration {
  InputDecoration merge(InputDecoration? other) {
    return InputDecoration(
      icon: other?.icon ?? icon,
      labelText: other?.labelText ?? labelText,
      labelStyle: other?.labelStyle ?? labelStyle,
      helperText: other?.helperText ?? helperText,
      helperStyle: other?.helperStyle ?? helperStyle,
      hintText: other?.hintText ?? hintText,
      hintStyle: other?.hintStyle ?? hintStyle,
      hintMaxLines: other?.hintMaxLines ?? hintMaxLines,
      errorText: other?.errorText ?? errorText,
      errorStyle: other?.errorStyle ?? errorStyle,
      errorMaxLines: other?.errorMaxLines ?? errorMaxLines,
      floatingLabelBehavior:
          other?.floatingLabelBehavior ?? floatingLabelBehavior,
      isCollapsed: other?.isCollapsed ?? isCollapsed,
      isDense: other?.isDense ?? isDense,
      contentPadding: other?.contentPadding ?? contentPadding,
      prefixIcon: other?.prefixIcon ?? prefixIcon,
      prefix: other?.prefix ?? prefix,
      prefixText: other?.prefixText ?? prefixText,
      prefixStyle: other?.prefixStyle ?? prefixStyle,
      suffixIcon: other?.suffixIcon ?? suffixIcon,
      suffix: other?.suffix ?? suffix,
      suffixText: other?.suffixText ?? suffixText,
      suffixStyle: other?.suffixStyle ?? suffixStyle,
      counter: other?.counter ?? counter,
      counterText: other?.counterText ?? counterText,
      counterStyle: other?.counterStyle ?? counterStyle,
      filled: other?.filled ?? filled,
      fillColor: other?.fillColor ?? fillColor,
      focusColor: other?.focusColor ?? focusColor,
      hoverColor: other?.hoverColor ?? hoverColor,
      errorBorder: other?.errorBorder ?? errorBorder,
      focusedBorder: other?.focusedBorder ?? focusedBorder,
      focusedErrorBorder: other?.focusedErrorBorder ?? focusedErrorBorder,
      disabledBorder: other?.disabledBorder ?? disabledBorder,
      enabledBorder: other?.enabledBorder ?? enabledBorder,
      border: other?.border ?? border,
      enabled: other?.enabled ?? enabled,
      semanticCounterText: other?.semanticCounterText ?? semanticCounterText,
      alignLabelWithHint: other?.alignLabelWithHint ?? alignLabelWithHint,
    );
  }
}
```