# Merge 2 immutable variables in Flutter / Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to merge those 2 widgets.

```
final InputDecoration inputDecoration1 = InputDecoration(
  errorText: "error",
  hintStyle: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
  ),
);
final InputDecoration inputDecoration2 = InputDecoration(
  hintStyle: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 3,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
    color: defaultGreyColor,
  ),
);
```

I know `copyWith`, but it only allows me to use it this way:

```
inputDecoration1.copyWith(
  hintStyle: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 3,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
    color: defaultGreyColor,
  ),
);
```

and not this way:

```
inputDecoration1.copyWith(inputDecoration2);
```

I can only use `inputDecoration2` as a variable.

Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: I don't think you can. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67559065/combine-merge-two-instances-of-inputdecoration-in-flutter

Comment: use extension function

Comment: What do you mean? @Doc

Comment: @Adi1231234 checkout my answer on using extension function.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final InputDecoration id = InputDecoration(
      errorText: "error",
      hintStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
      ),
    );
    final InputDecoration id2 = InputDecoration(
      hintStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 3,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );

    return Column(children: [
      TextFormField(decoration: id),
      TextFormField(decoration: id.copyID(id2))
    ]);
  }
}

extension ID on InputDecoration {
  InputDecoration copyID(InputDecoration other) {
    return this.copyWith(errorText: "other", hintStyle: other.hintStyle);
  }
}
```